# How to connect two parts using arrows or lines in Latex?

Tags: arrows

I need to insert something like the following in Latex.

[image]

I don't know how to create the arrows (or lines) that connect the letters to each other. Please help me to find a way how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402462/tikz-equivalent-of-pstricks-command-ncbar-in-text/402466#402466

Answer (score 4):

Ti*k*Z can also do it using nodes inside a tabular and the nodes are connected using a separate `tikzpicture` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,bm}
\newcommand\C[1]{\tikz[remember picture]{\node(#1)[inner sep=0pt]{\sffamily#1};}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}*7{c@{}}}
  \C{A}&\C{B}&\C{C}& $\bm\sim$ &\C{X}&\C{Y}&\C{Z}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,>=latex,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt,very thin]
\draw[->] (A) --++(0,-10pt) -| (X);
\draw[->] (B) --++(0,-12pt) -| (Y);
\draw[->] (C) --++(0,-14pt) -| (Z);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a code with `pst-node`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % load this package to compile with pdflatex -shell-escape (MacTeX, TX Live) or pdflatex --enable-write18 (MiKTeX)

\begin{document}

\Large\sffamily \bfseries
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep = 1pt, mnode = r, angle = -90, nodesep = 3pt]
    A & B & C & $\boldsymbol{ ∼ }$& X & Y & Z
    \psset{arrows = ->, arrowinset = 0.12, linewidth = 0.6pt, linejoin = 1}
    \ncbar[arm = 8pt]{1,1}{1,5}
    \ncbar[arm = 13pt]{1,2}{1,6}
    \ncbar[arm = 18pt]{1,3}{1,7}
\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\newcommand\C[1]{\rnode{#1}{\textsf{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\C{A}\C{B}\C{C}\textasciitilde\C{X}\C{Y}\C{Z}
\psset{arrows=->,linewidth=0.4pt,angleA=-90,nodesep=2pt}
\ncbar[arm=5pt]{A}{X}
\ncbar[arm=8pt]{B}{Y}   
\ncbar[arm=11pt]{C}{Z}

\end{document}
```

[image: []

Answer (score 2):

This answer is essentially copied from [Tjorbørn T.'s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402462/tikz-equivalent-of-pstricks-command-ncbar-in-text) and some other sources that are specified in the code. I'll be happy to remove this post once Tjorbørn uploads his answer. Tjorbørn's version of `\tikznode` is better than the `\rnode` command of `pstricks` in that it keeps the ambient math style, e.g. indices stay in `scriptstyle`. Here is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122415/mathchoice-and-tikzs-remember-picture
\makeatletter
\newcounter{tikznode}
\renewcommand*{\thetikznode}{tikznode@\the\value{tikznode}}
\newcommand*{\tikznodestyle}{%
  \refused{\thetikznode}%
  \ifcase\getrefbykeydefault{\thetikznode}{}{0} %
    \displaystyle
  \or\textstyle
  \or\scriptstyle
  \or\scriptscriptstyle
  \fi
}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402462/tikz-equivalent-of-pstricks-command-ncbar-in-text
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{%
\ifmmode%
  \stepcounter{tikznode}%
  \mathchoice
  {\def\@currentlabel{0}\label{\thetikznode}}%
  {\def\@currentlabel{1}\label{\thetikznode}}%
  {\def\@currentlabel{2}\label{\thetikznode}}%
  {\def\@currentlabel{3}\label{\thetikznode}}%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$\tikznodestyle #2$};
\else
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
\fi}
\makeatother

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402429/how-to-connect-two-parts-using-arrows-or-lines-in-latex
\newcommand{\TikzNCbar}[4][10pt]{%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[#2] (#3) --++(0,-#1) -| (#4);}}

\begin{document}
blabla
$\displaystyle\tikznode{A}{A}\textstyle\tikznode{B}{B}_{\tikznode{C}{C}_{\tikznode{D}{D}}}$
blabla
\tikznode{X}{X}\tikznode{Y}{Y}\tikznode{Z}{Z}\tikznode{W}{W}
blabla
\TikzNCbar{-}{A}{X}
\TikzNCbar[12pt]{->}{B}{Y}
\TikzNCbar[14pt]{<-}{C}{Z}
\TikzNCbar[-14pt]{<->,red}{D}{W}
\end{document}
```

and this is what it produces:

[image]

Obviously, this can also be used for Wick contractions and the like.

**ADDENDUM**: With the [updated version of the tikzmark library](https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark) this can be made much simpler. This automatically checks the math environment, which made my original answer look a bit lengthy, and spares you from having to type `\scriptstyle` and so on, which you might need to do using some of the other answers. (Nor are you required to run this with `xelatex`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcommand{\TikzNCbar}[4][10pt]{%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[#2] (#3) --++(0,-#1) -| (#4);}}

\begin{document}
blabla
$\displaystyle\tikzmarknode{A}{A}\textstyle\tikzmarknode{B}{B}_{\tikzmarknode{C}{C}_{\tikzmarknode{D}{D}}}$
blabla
\tikzmarknode{X}{X}\tikzmarknode{Y}{Y}\tikzmarknode{Z}{Z}\tikzmarknode{W}{W}
blabla
\TikzNCbar{-}{A}{X}
\TikzNCbar[12pt]{-latex}{B}{Y}
\TikzNCbar[14pt]{latex-}{C}{Z}
\TikzNCbar[-14pt]{latex-latex,red}{D}{W}
\end{document}
```

[image]