# Connecting characters with arrowed lines under text

Tags: boxes, arrows

I am trying to imitate exactly what I show on the following picture... some help, please? I mean the red box and lines and arrows. Thank you in advance...[image]

Comment: Take a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402429/how-to-connect-two-parts-using-arrows-or-lines-in-latex

Comment: It would be great if you could show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tikz` solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

La ecuaci\'on anterior se puede reducir as\'i:
\[
2x+5x^2-1-3-4x^2-5x=0\to
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\node[anchor=base,draw=red](equation){$x^2-3x-4=0$};
\node[below left = .4cm and 1.2cm](text){\llap{\raise.7ex\hbox{\textsc{forma general de la ecuaci\'on}}}};
\draw[->, red](text)-|(equation);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Great solution, it works perfect!!!

Comment: Excuse me, it works perfect except for the "[->,red]" in the \draw command... Any suggestions? For the moment, I have removed the [->,red], but then the line dosn't finish with an arrow

Comment: The code compiles fine for me and produces the output posted above.  What goes wrong when you include `[->,red]`?

Comment: I've got a message saying: "Argument of \language@active\arg> has an extra }. <inserted text> \par  1.555 \draw[->,red](text) -|(equation);
If just remove the [->,red], everything works properly. Thank you, Sandy

Comment: You must be using the `babel` package. There is a problem with the Spanish module in `babel` and the `<` and `>` symbols. There is a [solution posted here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166775/125871). Let me know if you still need assistance.

Comment: Thank you so much again, Sandy. That was the problem, now everything works ok!! Thank you!!!!