# How to write an overarrow between two symbols in formula?

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

How am I supposed to write an overarrow between two symbols in formula?

I am currently doing a report with relational algebra and normalization for databases, and what I need to do is representing a dependency between to elements in the same table, something like this:

[image]

Note that this arrow could be from a to d too, or they could be multiples ones in the same expression, like a to e and a to d and c to e.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There is an example on `texample.com` that looks very similar: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/oxidation-and-reduction/

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196958/how-to-draw-arrows-between-circled-coefficients-of-polynomials-using-tikz/196962#196962

Comment: And two more related questions: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/402429/121799) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/402462/121799)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `pstricks`: the elements to be linked are  defined as nodes, and I add node connections:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

    \begin{document}

\[ \begin{pspicture}
 T_{3,1}(\Rnode{d}{d}, \Rnode{e}{e}, \Rnode{a}{a}, \Rnode{c}{c})
 \psset{linewidth=0.4pt, linejoin=1, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.15, angle=90, nodesep=1pt, arm=1.1ex}
 \ncbar[offsetA=1pt]{a}{e} \ncbar[offsetA=-1pt, arm=1.3ex, nodesepB=-1pt]{a}{d}\ncbar[angle=-90]{c}{e}
 \end{pspicture} \]

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A pure TikZ solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand{\mypoint}[2]{\tikz[remember picture]{\node[inner sep=0pt](#1){$#2$};}}

\begin{document}
    \[
    T_{3,1}(d,\mypoint{tohere}{e},\mypoint{fromhere}{a},c)
    \]

    \tikz[overlay, remember picture]{\draw[-{Stealth[round]}] ([yshift=2pt]fromhere.north) -- ++(0,7pt) -| ([yshift=2pt]tohere.north);}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to put an arrow over two neighbouring letters, you could use `\overset`. But this won’t work, if one of the letters is part of an underlined section.

Another approach (but quite similar to [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196958/how-to-draw-arrows-between-circled-coefficients-of-polynomials-using-tikz/196962#196962)) using `tikzmark`s could be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

$T_{3,1}(d,\overset{\curvearrowleft}{e,a},c)$

\bigskip

$T_{3,1}(\underline{d,e\tikzmark{e}},a\tikzmark{a},c)$
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{ \draw[<-] ([xshift=-.5ex,yshift=1.5ex]pic cs:e) to[bend left=60] ([xshift=-.5ex,yshift=1.5ex]pic cs:a); }

\bigskip

$T_{3,1}(\underline{d\tikzmark{d},e},a\tikzmark{aa},c)$
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{ \draw[<-] ([xshift=-.5ex,yshift=2ex]pic cs:d) to[bend left] ([xshift=-.5ex,yshift=2ex]pic cs:aa); }


\end{document}
```

[image]