# Tikz equivalent of PSTricks commands ncbar and rnode

Tags: pstricks, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

Motivated by [this recent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402429/how-to-connect-two-parts-using-arrows-or-lines-in-latex), I tried to cook up a `tikz` based solution using the code provided in the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55068/is-there-a-tikz-equivalent-to-the-pstricks-ncbar-command?noredirect=1&lq=1). More precisely, I tried to cook up equivalents of the `pstricks` `\rnode` and `\ncline` commands in `tikz`. This is what I got:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax\ifmmode\savebox{\tempbox}{\ensuremath{#2}}
\makebox[\wd\tempbox]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=-0.8ex]%
 \node[minimum width=\wd\tempbox] (#1) {\ensuremath{#2}};}
\else\savebox{\tempbox}{#2}
\makebox[0.5\wd\tempbox]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=-0.8ex,minimum width=\wd\tempbox]%
 \node[minimum width=\wd\tempbox] (#1) {#2};}\fi}

\tikzset{
    ncbar angle/.initial=-90,
    ncbar/.style={
        to path=(\tikztostart)
        -- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)
        -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztostart)$)
        -- (\tikztotarget)
    },
    ncbar/.default=0.5cm
}

\begin{document}
blabla \tikznode{A}{A}\tikznode{B}{B}\tikznode{C}{C} blabla
\tikznode{X}{X}\tikznode{Y}{Y}\tikznode{Z}{Z} blabla
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[->] (A) to [ncbar=0.4] (X);}%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[->] (B) to [ncbar=0.5] (Y);}%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[->] (C) to [ncbar=0.6] (Z);}%
\end{document}
```

It produces:

[image]

which looks not completely unreasonable. However, it seems unreasonably complicated and I assume that there is a much more elegant and stable solution. For instance, I need to shift the baseline by hand using `baseline=-0.8ex`. This doesn't seem right. I also need to compute the width of the text and multiply it by an arbitrary factor of 0.5, which again appears odd. Last but not least, I have to distinguish between math and text modes. (Yes, I know that in principle there is `\mathchoice` that may be used, but I feel that I've chosen an unnecessarily complicated approach, so I refrained from building this in.) My question is if someone knows how to make this more elegant and, in particular, stable.

Comment: Why do you have to distinguish between text and math mode? `\tikz` works in both, and the mode of the text in the node isn't affected by the mode in which the `\tikz` is placed.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. because I'd also like to use it in math mode. More precisely, if I type `$\tikz{\node(x){x};}$`, the `x` is not in math mode, but with `$\tikznode{x}{x}$` it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would probably do

```
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{%
\ifmmode%
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};%
\else
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
\fi}
```

By setting the baseline to the `base` anchor of the node, you don't have to use some specific value. With `inner sep=0pt` you wont get any extra space around the text in the node.

Note also that I removed the `overlay` option. That option means that you get a zero-size bounding box, which you don't want here.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{%
\ifmmode%
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};%
\else
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
\fi}

\tikzset{
    ncbar angle/.initial=-90,
    ncbar/.style={
        to path=(\tikztostart)
        -- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)
        -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztostart)$)
        -- (\tikztotarget)
    },
    ncbar/.default=0.5cm
}

\begin{document}
blabla \tikznode{A}{A}$\tikznode{B}{B}$\tikznode{C}{C} blabla
\tikznode{X}{X}\tikznode{Y}{Y}\tikznode{Z}{Z} blabla
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[->] (A) to [ncbar=0.4] (X);
\draw[->] (B) to [ncbar=0.5] (Y);
\draw[->] (C) to [ncbar=0.6] (Z);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want to implement `\mathchoice` in this, you get problems, because all the four different choices are typeset. Hence, the naive implementation of

```
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{%
\ifmmode%
\mathchoice
  {\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$\displaystyle #2$};}%
  {\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$\textstyle #2$};}%
  {\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$\scriptstyle #2$};}%
  {\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$\scriptscriptstyle #2$};}%
\else
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
\fi}
```

doesnt't work, because the node name will always refer to the scriptscript-version, which isn't used at all in the three other styles. So for the example above, where the `B` is in textstyle, you get an arrow pointing out of the page.

Perhaps unsurprisingly though, someone has wondered about that problem before, and Heiko Oberdiek provided a solution to it in [mathchoice and tikz's remember picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122415/mathchoice-and-tikzs-remember-picture). The `refmathstyle` package he made has not yet been published on CTAN though, and the link to it in that answer is dead, so here is the non-package version:

[image: output of below code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122415/mathchoice-and-tikzs-remember-picture
\makeatletter
\newcounter{tikznode}
\renewcommand*{\thetikznode}{tikznode@\the\value{tikznode}}
\newcommand*{\tikznodestyle}{%
  \refused{\thetikznode}%
  \ifcase\getrefbykeydefault{\thetikznode}{}{0} %
    \displaystyle
  \or\textstyle
  \or\scriptstyle
  \or\scriptscriptstyle
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{%
\ifmmode%
  \stepcounter{tikznode}%
  \mathchoice
  {\def\@currentlabel{0}\label{\thetikznode}}%
  {\def\@currentlabel{1}\label{\thetikznode}}%
  {\def\@currentlabel{2}\label{\thetikznode}}%
  {\def\@currentlabel{3}\label{\thetikznode}}%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$\tikznodestyle #2$};
\else
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
\fi}
\makeatother

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55068/is-there-a-tikz-equivalent-to-the-pstricks-ncbar-command
\tikzset{
    ncbar angle/.initial=-90,
    ncbar/.style={
        to path=(\tikztostart)
        -- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)
        -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztostart)$)
        -- (\tikztotarget)
    },
    ncbar/.default=0.5cm
}

\begin{document}
blabla
$\displaystyle\tikznode{A}{A}\textstyle\tikznode{B}{B}_{\tikznode{C}{C}_{\tikznode{D}{D}}}$
blabla
\tikznode{X}{X}\tikznode{Y}{Y}\tikznode{Z}{Z}\tikznode{W}{W}
blabla
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[->] (A) to [ncbar=0.4] (X);
\draw[->] (B) to [ncbar=0.5] (Y);
\draw[->] (C) to [ncbar=0.6] (Z);
\draw[->] (D) to [ncbar=0.6] (W);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there are a number of caveats I haven't considered, so it this is useless let me know, I can always delete it.

Comment: That's a great trick, so please don't delete it. Do you want to post it also as an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402429/how-to-connect-two-parts-using-arrows-or-lines-in-latex)? (Since even you are a bit struggling with the math mode, perhaps it's really worthwhile to build in `\mathchoice`.)

Comment: @marmot  (I rarely/never dig in to lower-level stuff, so there is a *lot* I don't know.) I've never used `\mathchoice`, but you get some problems because all four options are typeset, meaning that the node names get overwritten. I can give an impractical workaround for that, I don't know if there are any good ones.

Comment: @marmot By the way, `\mathchoice` has nothing to with distinguishing between text and math mode, which it seems like you think.

Comment: Hmmh, I thought it would discriminate the different math modes `\displaystyle`, `normal`, `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`. Probably I misinterpreted [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148740/what-is-mathchoice). Anyway, you're right, I have a hard time implementing it.

Comment: @marmot Yes, but that is a different distinction than math vs. text.

Comment: Yes, what I tried to do is `\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax%
\ifmmode\relax\mathchoice{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node(#1){\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}};}{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node(#1){\ensuremath{#2}};}{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node(#1){\ensuremath{#2}};}%
{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node(#1){\ensuremath{#2}};}
\else
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
\fi}`, but, as you anticipated, hell breaks loose.

Comment: @marmot See updated answer, which isn't good, but it's something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69086/discussion-between-marmot-and-torbjorn-t).

Comment: There is actually an issue: your command does not harmonize with `amsmath` equation environments. There are error messages of the type `! Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'tikznode@3' will be lost.`. However, if one continues compiling, the output is OK.

Comment: @marmot For that I can safely blame Heiko, the error comes from the code I borrowed from his post.

Comment: I certainly agree. Perhaps that's the reason why he did not write the package. Of course, one may cook up a workaround, but chances are that this will cause conflicts with other packages.

Comment: @marmot I've added a version of `\tikznode` to the `tikzmark` library (and renamed it `\tikzmarknode`).  Since `remember picture` already writes something to the aux file, I use that instead of needing an extra label.  I haven't tried working with amsmath as yet.  Code is on github.

Comment: First experiment with amsmath seems to work, can you send me some code that doesn't with the above so that I can test?

Comment: @LoopSpace Thanks! (Did you downvote my recent answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/450135/121799)? When I renamed the macro there precisely in order to avoid the conflict with your nice library, *not* to say anything bad to it. If you did not downvote, than this question/answer may be a playground example, and I will be happy to delete my answer to see yours.)

Comment: No!  I didn't downvote!  (can't remember when I last downvoted here, but regardless your answer wouldn't be one that I would).  And please don't delete your answer there.  It is a good answer.

Comment: I'm trying to use this solution to get ncbars that connect variables in equations. I'm getting bars that come off at not-quite-90-degree angles just like shown in the 2nd picture of this answer. That's not what I want, even if the connected elements have different heights or depths. What's causing it and how can I fix it?

Comment: @DavidWright As for why, that's what `ncbar` does. The connecting line is parallel to the line between the two points. If the bar should always be horizontal, you could change the style to the much simpler `ncbar/.style={to path={(\tikztostart) -- ++(0,-#1) -| (\tikztotarget)}}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's buried in the comments on Torbjørn's answer, this is just to note that this is now a part of the [`tikzmark`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) package, and correctly handles the different math modes.  Here's a demo:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/402462/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\tikzset{
    ncbar angle/.initial=-90,
    ncbar/.style={
        to path=(\tikztostart)
        -- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)
        -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztostart)$)
        -- (\tikztotarget)
    },
    ncbar/.default=0.5cm
}

\begin{document}
blabla \tikzmarknode{A}{A}\(\tikzmarknode{B}{B}^{\tikzmarknode{C}{C}}\) blabla
\tikzmarknode{X}{X}\tikzmarknode{Y}{Y}\tikzmarknode{Z}{Z} blabla
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[->] (A) to [ncbar=0.4] (X);
\draw[->] (B) to [ncbar=0.5] (Y);
\draw[->] (C) to [ncbar=0.6] (Z);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Demonstration of tikzmarknode with different math modes]

The lines from `C` to `Z` are angled because the bottoms of the nodes are at different levels.  I don't know what the original PSTricks `ncline` does in that circumstance so I left that code as it is in Torbjørn's answer.