# How to draw lines on a tikz-cd diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I am drawing a matrix using tikz-cd. I would like to draw some vertical and horizontal lines on it too to indicate particular submatrices but I don't understand the syntax. This is my M(N)WE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=3pt, row sep=5pt,nodes={inner sep=0pt,align=center,
text width={width("20")}}]
&&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
0&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\
0&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
0&3&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
0&4&3&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6
\foreach \x in {1,3}
{
    \draw 
    ([yshift=-3,xshift=-.125\pgflinewidth]mat-\x-1.south west) --   
    ([yshift=-3,xshift=-.125\pgflinewidth]mat-\x-12.south east);
}
\foreach \y in {2}
{
    \draw 
    ([yshift=.5\pgflinewidth]mat-1-\y.north east) -- 
    ([yshift=.5\pgflinewidth]mat-14-\y.south east);
}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

This is syntactically incorrect but works if you remove the \foreach loops. How can I use the \foreach...\draw commands with a tikz-cd drawn matrix?

Comment: You seem to be mixing two things. Yes, `tikz-cd` is using a `tikz` `matrix`, but the `tikzcd` environment does not give you a `tikzpicture` environment in which you can just use `\draw`.

Comment: @marmot Yes I am definitely confused. Is there some way to use tikz-cd to make the matrix and also use \draw to draw on it? Or alternatively some other way to draw horizontal and vertical lines to separate submatrices?

Comment: Yes: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405152/121799

Comment: @marmot Ah. I tried just now https://bpaste.net/show/db6d4ebda072 but this doesn't work because mat doesn't exist. I need some pure tikz-cd solution it seems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=3pt, row sep=5pt,nodes={inner sep=0pt,align=center,
text width={width("20")}},nodes in empty cells,
execute at end picture={
\foreach \x in {1,3}
{
    \draw 
    ([yshift=-3,xshift=-.125\pgflinewidth]\tikzcdmatrixname-\x-1.south west) --   
    ([yshift=-3,xshift=-.125\pgflinewidth]\tikzcdmatrixname-\x-12.south east);
}
\foreach \y in {3}
{
    \draw 
    ([yshift=.5\pgflinewidth]\tikzcdmatrixname-1-\y.north west) -- 
    ([yshift=.5\pgflinewidth]\tikzcdmatrixname-6-\y.south west);
}}]
&&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
0&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\
0&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
0&3&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
0&4&3&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I was employing [Henri Menke's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405152/121799) and added `nodes in empty cells` and changed some numbers to only use existing nodes.

**ADDENDUM**: If you want to the lines right in the middle between the cells without having to add all the shifts by fractions of the line width, you could use the `calc` library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=3pt, row sep=5pt,nodes={inner sep=0pt,align=center,
text width={width("20")}},nodes in empty cells,
execute at end picture={
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xp using {int(\x+1)}] in {1,3}
{
    \draw ($(\tikzcdmatrixname-\x-2.south)!0.5!(\tikzcdmatrixname-\xp-2.north)$)
    coordinate (aux)
    ([xshift=-.1em]\tikzcdmatrixname.west|-aux) --   
    ([xshift=.1em]\tikzcdmatrixname.east|-aux);
}
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \ym using {int(\y-1)}] in {3}
{
    \draw ($(\tikzcdmatrixname-1-\y.west)!0.5!(\tikzcdmatrixname-1-\ym.east)$)
    coordinate (aux)
    ([yshift=0.1ex]\tikzcdmatrixname.north-|aux) -- 
    ([yshift=0.1ex]\tikzcdmatrixname.south-|aux);
}}]
&&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
0&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\
0&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
0&3&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
0&4&3&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

As for the question what this might be good for: there are certain things that are somewhat harder to achieve with a table like e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,through,backgrounds} 
\tikzset{circle through 3 points/.style n args={3}{% 
insert path={let \p1=($(#1)!0.5!(#2)$), 
\p2=($(#1)!0.5!(#3)$), 
\p3=($(#1)!0.5!(#2)!1!-90:(#2)$), 
\p4=($(#1)!0.5!(#3)!1!90:(#3)$), 
\p5=(intersection of \p1--\p3 and \p2--\p4) 
in }, 
at={(\p5)}, 
circle through= {(#1)} 
}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=3pt, row sep=5pt,nodes={inner sep=0pt,align=center,
text width={width("20")}},nodes in empty cells,
execute at end picture={
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xp using {int(\x+1)}] in {1,3}
{
    \draw ($(\tikzcdmatrixname-\x-2.south)!0.5!(\tikzcdmatrixname-\xp-2.north)$)
    coordinate (aux)
    ([xshift=-.1em]\tikzcdmatrixname.west|-aux) --   
    ([xshift=.1em]\tikzcdmatrixname.east|-aux);
}
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \ym using {int(\y-1)}] in {3}
{
    \draw ($(\tikzcdmatrixname-1-\y.west)!0.5!(\tikzcdmatrixname-1-\ym.east)$)
    coordinate (aux)
    ([yshift=0.1ex]\tikzcdmatrixname.north-|aux) -- 
    ([yshift=0.1ex]\tikzcdmatrixname.south-|aux);
}
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \node[circle through 3
 points={\tikzcdmatrixname-2-2}{\tikzcdmatrixname-3-1}{\tikzcdmatrixname-3-3},
 fill=blue!20]{}; 
\end{scope}
}]
&&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
0&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\
0&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
0&3&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
0&4&3&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Yet for many purposes, the [table approach suggested by Joule V](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481728/121799) is just fine or even better. It really depends on what you want to do in the end.

Comment: I'm not aiming to make a war but I do think the last figure is still not difficult ;) We just need some help of a `remember picture, overlay` Ti*k*Z picture :)

Comment: @JouleV This meant to be really friendly. AFAIK you cannot achieve this with `remember picture` easily because you cannot draw it on the background after the table is "done" unless you use `atbegshi` or something like this, or do something with `blend mode` .

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun: if you want to make that matrix, why don't use a table? The code is *much* shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{cc|cccccccccc}
    &&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\\hline
    &0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
    0&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\\hline
    0&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
    0&3&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
    0&4&3&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Coloring the text is not difficult, isn't it? If you want to draw some arrows, `\tikzmark` may be an option. Anyway, if I were you, I would use a simple table. :)

---

#### Add an arrow

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{cc|cccccccccc}
    &&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\\hline
    &0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
    0&\tikz[baseline,remember picture]\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0pt] (node1) {1};&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\\hline
    0&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
    0&3&2&1&0&1&2&\tikz[baseline,remember picture]\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0pt] (node2) {3};&4&5&6&7\\
    0&4&3&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red,very thick,-latex] (node1) -- (node2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

#### Color row(s)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{cc|cccccccccc}
    \rowcolor{red!20}&&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\\hline
    \rowcolor{red!20}&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
    0&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\\hline
    0&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
    0&3&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
    0&4&3&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

#### Color column(s)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{cc|ccc>{\columncolor{yellow!50}}cc>{\columncolor{green!20}}ccccc}
    &&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\\hline
    &0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
    0&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\\hline
    0&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
    0&3&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
    0&4&3&2&1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*It is never impossible to work with tables using table commands* :)

Comment: I will also add arrows in the table and color some of the elements.

Comment: And: most users load `tikz` anyway for the `tikzlings`. ;-)

Comment: Can you color an entire submatrix of a table out of interest? Say rows 1-2 and columns 4-6?

Comment: @Anush To color, you have `\cellcolor`. To make arrows, you can have a look at [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/408181/156344).

Comment: @Anush I edited my answer: I added some ways to add arrows, color columns and rows.