# tikzmark not working as expected

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmark

I'm trying to strike out a column and a row from a matrix, and I get it to work if I define the `tikzmark` myself (from I post I found on the internet). I understand, however, that `tikzmark` is now included by default in the tikz library, so I tried to use it instead. But I get errors of names not defined. This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, tikzmark}

%% draw horizontal and vertical lines in tables
%\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base] (#1) {$#2$};}

\newcommand{\DrawVLine}[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[#1] (#2.north) -- (#3.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\DrawHLine}[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[#1] (#2.west) -- (#3.east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \tikzmark{top}{ a } & 0 & -a & \tikzmark{right}{-c} \\
 0 & b & 0 & -b \\ 
 -a & 0 & a & k \\
 \tikzmark{bottom}{d} & -b  & d & c \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation*}
\DrawVLine[red, ultra thick, opacity=0.5]{top}{bottom}
\DrawHLine[red, ultra thick, opacity=0.5]{top}{right}

\end{document}
```

which doesn't work. But if you uncomment the definition of `tikzmark` and remove it from `\usetikzlibrary` then I get the expected result:

[image]

Comment: I guess you confuse `\tikzmark` with some `\tikznode` command, which is also around. Referring to coordinates from `\tikzmark` requires a `pic cs:`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're not using the `tikzmark` library correctly. First of all, the tikzmark command takes one mandatory argument, not two as in your commented out version, and one option. More importantly, to refer to *coordinates* you need to use `pic cs:`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}

%% draw horizontal and vertical lines in tables
%\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base] (#1) {$#2$};}

\newcommand{\DrawVLine}[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[#1] (pic cs:#2) -- (pic cs:#3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\DrawHLine}[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[#1] (pic cs:#2) -- (pic cs:#3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \tikzmark{top}a & 0 & -a & -c\tikzmark{right} \\
 0 & b & 0 & -b \\ 
 -a & 0 & a & k \\
 \tikzmark{bottom}d & -b  & d & c \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation*}
\DrawVLine[red, ultra thick, opacity=0.5]{top}{bottom}
\DrawHLine[red, ultra thick, opacity=0.5]{top}{right}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, this *does* work, but yes, the output is not optimal. The perhaps best way to go is to call your `\tikzmark` command `\tikznode` and then use it as you suggest (with the baseline option, as in the `\tikznode` commands that you can find e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402466/121799)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{%
\ifmmode%
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};%
\else
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
\fi}

%% draw horizontal and vertical lines in tables
%\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base] (#1) {$#2$};}

\newcommand{\DrawVLine}[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[#1] (#2.north) -- (#3.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\DrawHLine}[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[#1] (#2.west) -- (#3.east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
 {}\tikznode{top}{a} & 0 & -a & {}\tikznode{right}{-c} \\
 0 & b & 0 & -b \\ 
 -a & 0 & a & k \\
 {}\tikznode{bottom}{d} & -b  & d & c \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation*}
\DrawVLine[red, ultra thick, opacity=0.5]{top}{bottom}
\DrawHLine[red, ultra thick, opacity=0.5]{top}{right}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me stress that the `\tikzmark` command is rather sophisticated as it discriminates between being called inside or outside a `tikzpicture`.

Comment: Do you think it's better I just use my `tikzmark` definition? The output is optimal in this case.

Comment: @aaragon I added what I would do. Notice that because of some amsmath hacks one has to use `{}` before the `\tikznode`s, which is not necessary under "normal" circumstances, where `\tikznode` detects the math mode and typesets accordingly. If you don't want to have the darker color where the lines intersect, you can work with `transparency group`s, but this would require rewriting your macros.

Comment: @aaragon And yes, I also like the output of your definition, I just would not call the macro `\tikzmark` as you may want to use the "real" `\tikzmark` in parallel.

Answer (score 4):

I personally it'd be simpler to use the `\matrix` environment in Tikz, where you can assign a name to the whole matrix and, in turn, to the nodes.

### Output

[image: highlighted matrix picture]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newcommand{\DrawV}[3][]{%
    \draw[#1, line width=3mm, opacity=.2] (#2.north) -- (#3.south);
}

\newcommand{\DrawH}[3][]{%
    \draw[#1, line width=3mm, opacity=.2] (#2.west) -- (#3.east);
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[}, right delimiter={]}] {%
    a & 0 & -a & -c \\
    0 & b & 0 & -b \\ 
   -a & 0 & a & k \\
    d & -b & d & c \\
};

\DrawV[red]{m-1-1}{m-4-1}
\DrawH[green]{m-1-2}{m-1-4}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't actually use that because I need to use a `blockarray` to also number the indexes of the matrix.

Comment: @aaragon Sorry, I rarely if ever use matrices, but do you mean indexing (i.e. adding sort of headings to) the singular rows and columns or the matrix itself?