# Tikzmark; Tangent arrows

Tags: tikzmark

I am happy with this but I'd like to make the two drawn arrows tangent. Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
      \textcolor{blue}{1\tikzmarknode{A}{}2}\bigg ( \dfrac{x\tikzmarknode{B} 
{+}4}{4}-\dfrac{x\tikzmarknode{C}{-}3}{3} \bigg )&=\textcolor{blue}{12}\bigg 
( \dfrac{11}{12} \bigg ) \\
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[->,blue,thick,smooth,shorten >=1pt,shorten<=1pt,out=65,in=110,distance=.6cm] ([yshift=6pt]A.north) to ([yshift=2pt]B.north);
\draw[->,blue,thick,smooth,shorten >=1pt,shorten<=1pt,out=65,in=110,distance=.6cm] ([yshift=6pt]A.north) to ([yshift=2pt]C.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This program gives:

[image]

BUT I am trying to get the two drawn lines tangent as in this image:

[image]

Comment: Try out=90 for both and play with in until you like the result... second arrows in should be somehow greater than first... for example first in 110, second in 125

Comment: You've not provided a MWE that we can compile.  Also, at least for my version of `tikzmark`, there is no command `\tikzmarknode`.

Comment: Understood it is the newest version and not available on CTAN yet. My apologies.

Comment: Technically, the lines are tangent.  It's just that they don't stay tangent for long.  Try using the `looseness` key on the longer arrow to get it to sweep out a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a few liberties with your original posting.  But here's a result.  I elaborate below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[inner sep=0pt] (#1) {};}
\newcommand\tikzdouble[2]{\tikzmark{#11}#2\tikzmark{#12}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{5in}
\begin{align*}
      \textcolor{blue}{\tikzdouble{A}{12}}
        \bigg (  
                 \dfrac{\tikzdouble{B}{x+4}}{4}
                -\dfrac{\tikzdouble{C}{x-3}}{3} 
        \bigg )
        &=
      \textcolor{blue}{12}
        \bigg ( 
                 \dfrac{11}{12} 
        \bigg ) 
      \\
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,
  my arrow style/.style={->,blue,thick,smooth,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt}]
  \foreach \myn in {A,B,C}
    {
      \coordinate (\myn) at ($(\myn1)!0.5!(\myn2)$);
    }

  \draw[my arrow style] ([yshift=8pt]A) .. controls ++(60:12pt) and ++(120:12pt) .. ([yshift=5pt]B);
  \draw[my arrow style] ([yshift=8pt]A) .. controls ++(60:28pt) and ++(120:28pt) .. ([yshift=5pt]C);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So, the first thing I've done is use the `standalone` class and because of that I have to put the `align` environment inside a `minipage` so it knows what the *paper* width is.

Next, I'm not sure what `\tikzmarknode` is supposed to actually do.  I made my best guess and made my own command `\tikzdouble`.  I'm also guessing that `\tikzmarknode` does some of the work I'm doing in the `tikzpicture` environment on its own.

I've also defined a *style* for the arrows to make the code a bit more readable.

The primary gist of what I've done is to use control points in lieu of the `in=` and `out=` keys for the directive `to`.

## Update

Here I've added a bit more muscle to `\tikzdouble` to do more of the grunt work for placing the nodes appropriately.  But, it has been set up to operate in math mode.

[image]

The code

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit}

%% this `tikzdouble` has been designed specifically for use in math mode
%% particular where it comes to measuring the height and depth of the text
%% being marked on either side with a node.
\newcommand\tikzdouble[2]{%%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\aetmpA{depth("$#2$")}%%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\aetmpB{height("$#2$")}%%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[inner sep=0pt] at (0,-\aetmpA pt)  (#1/tmp/1) {};%%
  #2%%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[inner sep=0pt] at (0,\aetmpB pt) (#1/tmp/2) {};%%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[fit=(#1/tmp/1) (#1/tmp/2),inner sep=0pt] (#1) {};%%
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{5in}
  \begin{align*}
    \textcolor{blue}{\tikzdouble{A}{12}}
      \bigg (  
               \dfrac{\tikzdouble{B}{x+4}}{4}
              -\dfrac{\tikzdouble{C}{x-3}}{3} 
      \bigg )
      &=
    \textcolor{blue}{12}
      \bigg ( 
               \dfrac{11}{12} 
      \bigg ) 
  \end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,
  my arrow style/.style={->,blue,thick,smooth,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt}]

  \draw[my arrow style] (A.north) .. controls ++(60:12pt) and ++(120:12pt) .. (B.north);
  \draw[my arrow style] (A.north) .. controls ++(60:32pt) and ++(120:24pt) .. (C.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The result is what I am looking for. I need some time to try and adapt it to my original posting. I forgot about the new version . It is discuss in this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450135/tikzmark-arrows-exponents-and-bases . I believe Loopspace created it.