# Highlight equation with boxes and arrows

Tags: equations

[image]

I have not tried this yet and have no ideas for this? could anyone can help? Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: If you search the site for "highlight equation", "highlight equation with arrows" (that are sensible titles for a question; your title helps little here  ;-) ) and browse the tag `tikzmark` you'll find plenty of examples.

Comment: For example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140529/graphics-equations-put-text-on-equations https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450135/tikzmark-arrows-exponents-and-bases

Comment: yes, many thanks! I have had no keyword for searching!

Comment: I took a liberty and change title of your question that bow better correspond to your problem. If you not liked, you can revert my edition.

Answer (score 6):

This could be a solution combining `tcolorbox` and `TiKZ`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tcbset{
    boxmath/.style 2 args={%
        enhanced,
        sharp corners, colback=white,
        colframe=#1, remember as=#2, size=fbox}
    }
    
\begin{document}
\[
e^x=\tcboxmath[boxmath={blue}{approx}]{1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots++\frac{x^n}{n!}}+\tcboxmath[boxmath={red}{trunc}]{\frac{x^{n+1}}{{n+1}!}+\dots}
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, font=\sffamily]
\draw[blue,->] (approx.north) --++(120:5mm) node[anchor=south]{Approximation};
\draw[red,->] (trunc.north) --++(70:5mm) node[anchor=south]{Truncation Errors};
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror, raise=3pt, amplitude=2mm}] (approx.south west)--(trunc.south east) node[below=3mm, midway]{Exact mathematical formulation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]