# tikz or how to do this in LaTex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, matrices

I am trying to get this to work in Latex, this is the output I am looking for:

[image: Desired output]

This is the code I have so far, but I'm not getting what I want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, decorations.pathreplacing,shapes,shapes.geometric,hobby,patterns,babel,matrix,calc}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Mat}{Mat}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[
decoration = {
brace,amplitude=5pt},
baseline = (current bounding box.west),
strip/.style = {
draw=MediumPurple,%color
line width=1.1em, opacity=0.4,
line cap=round ,% only if you like them ...
},
stripp/.style = {
draw=LightSkyBlue,%color
line width=1.8em, opacity=0.4,
line cap=round ,% only if you like them ...
},
]
\matrix (mtrxx)  [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),
column sep=.5em,   
nodes={text height=2ex,text width=1.5ex}]
{
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
5 & 6 \\
};

\begin{scope}[xshift = 6cm]
\matrix (mtrxz)  [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),
column sep=.5em,
nodes={text height=2ex,text width=1.5ex}]
{
-1 & 2 & 0 & 3 \\
1 & 0 & 4 & -1 \\
};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
\matrix {mtrxi}  [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),
column sep=.5em,
nodes={text height=2ex,text width=1.5ex}]
{
$3 \times 2$ & & & & & & & & & $2 \times 4$ \\
};
\end{scope}

\node[color=black] at ([shift={(-12mm,-3mm)}]mtrxx-2-1.north) {$A =$};
\node[color=black] at ([shift={(-12mm,0mm)}]mtrxz-2-1.north) {$B =$};

\end{tikzpicture} \\

\end{document}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi ! I am not a scientist at all, but is tikz really needed ? Can't you do this with the usual math mode ? Just a naive question.

Comment: I have tried, but I had trouble getting it, unless you have a way to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't, being an historian. But using tikz looks overkill to me. I suggest adding the math-mode tag to your question.

Comment: @Sephya: Can you provide a better title to your question? Doing "this" is very generic... be more descriptive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a proposal in the matrices are produced in the boring standard way and then annotated with Ti*k*Z. To this end, [`\tikznode`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402466/121799) is employed, which will be superseded by `\tikzmarknode` in the hopefully not so far future, when the `tikzmark` library will be extended by this command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402466/121799
\ifmmode%
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};%
\else
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
\fi}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Mat}{Mat}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A=&\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\tikznode{5}{5} & \tikznode{6}{6} \\
\end{pmatrix}
&
B=&
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 2 & 0 & 3 \\
\tikznode{1}{1} & 0 & 4 & \tikznode{m1}{-1} \\
\end{pmatrix} \\[1cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \draw[latex-latex] ([yshift=-3pt]5.south) -- ([yshift=-3pt]6.south)
  node[midway,below](dimA){$3\times2$};
 \draw[latex-latex] ([yshift=-3pt]1.south) -- ([yshift=-3pt]m1.south)
  node[midway,below](dimB){$2\times4$};
 \draw[latex-latex] ([xshift=-6pt]dimA.south east) -- ++(0,-0.3) -|
  ([xshift=6pt]dimB.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
=&\begin{pmatrix}
 \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
 \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
 \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
 \bullet & \bullet & \tikznode{24}{24} & \bullet \\
\end{pmatrix}
&&%\begin{array}{r@{}l}
\tikznode{AB}{$(AB)_{33}$}%&
=\begin{pmatrix} \tikznode{5p}{5} & \tikznode{6p}{6}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0\\\tikznode{4p}{4}\end{pmatrix} %\\
%&
=6\cdot0+6\cdot4=\tikznode{24p}{24}
%\end{array}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[latex-latex] (24) to[out=-30,in=-150] (AB);
\path (5p.south) -- (6p.south) coordinate[midway] (aux);
\draw[latex-] (4p.south) to[out=-90,in=90] ++ (0.5,-1) node[below right](B3){3rd column of $B$};
\draw[latex-] (aux) to[out=-90,in=90] ++ (-0.5,-1) node[below left](A3){3rd row of $A$};
\end{tikzpicture} \\[0.5cm]
\end{align*}
Some more text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Every time I click through an answer by you I get a gentle kick towards updating `tikzmark`!  It *will* happen soon, I promise!

Comment: @marmot Yes, I know!  The hold-up (apart from general busyness) is that I want to merge it with `savenodes` (https://github.com/loopspace/savenodes) as I think they'd work well together.

Comment: @LoopSpace Yes, I guess there is a huge demand for that. And thanks for doing all this. (There is something that sort of bothers me when writing these answers: I always have to add vertical space by hand such that the overlay pics to not run over the subsequent text. The only reason for `Some more text.` here is that I wanted to check that this does not happen. In principle, I think, it should be possible to compute and automatically insert this space. Have you ever thought about this?)

Comment: One of the issues there is that the overlaid stuff is viewed by TeX as being anchored to where it is specified (so there's a zero-size box somewhere), so giving it some size is tricky as you want its actual size not its TeX-size (which would include that zero-size box).  I guess you could stick a `\tikzmark` in each overlaid bit and then add enough space that you're below all those marks.  That could be automated, I guess.