# Character within a rounded textbox

Tags: button

this will be my first question here so sorry for asking such a noob question. How do you render the image(python text inside a rounded corner textbox) below using pure LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: You can use TikZ for this. Something like \tikz\node[draw,rounded corners]{Python};

Comment: But I believe this is an XY problem, you might want to draw a diagram or something like that.

Comment: There is the `menukeys` package, try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{menukeys}

\begin{document}
\keys{Python}
\end{document}`. But I agree with @Fractal that you might be better off if you just used Ti*k*Z.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a small rounded rectangle around a word inline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458864/how-to-add-a-small-rounded-rectangle-around-a-word-inline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution using the Ti*k*Z package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\HappyNewYear[1]{\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]{
  \node[draw,rounded corners] (x) {#1};
}}
\begin{document}
\HappyNewYear{Python} is a programming language, but \HappyNewYear{snake} isn't.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need colour, a box from the simple `fancybox` package will do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox} 

\begin{document}

\ovalbox{\quad\sffamily Python\quad}
\bigskip 

\Ovalbox{\quad\sffamily Python\quad}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For more sophisticated needs, you have the `mdframed` or `tcolorbox` package.