# Control vertical placement of tikz picture in text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm doing something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\ccor}[1]{%
    \tikz[remember picture]{%
        \node[fill=black!20,anchor=base](color){#1};%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    write some text with \ccor{color background}.
\end{document}
```

and I'm just wondering if there is a way of lowering the picture a little so that the text is all aligned.

[image]

Comment: Do you agree that the answers here solve your problem? [How to add a small rounded rectangle around a word inline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/458864/138900)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I  think the baseline option is better as follows --

```
\tikz[remember picture,
      baseline=(color.base)%<-----------------------added
     ]
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\ccor}[1]{%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(color.base)]{%
        \node[fill=black!20,anchor=base](color){#1};%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    
    write some text with \ccor{color background}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've changed the command to:

```
\newcommand{\ccor}[1]{%
    \tikzmarknode{pos}{\vphantom{AA}}
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
        \node[fill=facebook!20,anchor=west](codigo)at (pos.west){\texttt{#1}};
        }
    \sbox0{\hphantom{#1}}
    \hspace{\wd0}
    }
```

and the result is satisfactory.