# How would I move the tikznode below underline

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was wondering how I could lower the line below the underline in this image?

[image]

Here's the code I have so far :

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,latexsym,amsfonts}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{physics}                % partial derivatives
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections, decorations.pathreplacing,shapes,shapes.geometric,hobby,patterns,babel,matrix,calc,snakes,backgrounds,shapes.multipart,shadows.blur}

    \newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402466/121799
    \ifmmode%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};%
    \else
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
    \fi}

    \begin{document}

    Soit $A$ une matrice $\triangle$ supérieure (voir exercice pour : inférieure). Les valeurs propres de $A$ sont les racines de $p_{A}(\lambda)$ : \\ \\
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
        \det(A - \lambda I) &= \mqty|a_{1\,1} - \lambda & a_{1\,2} & & & \\ & a_{2\,2} - \lambda & a_{2\,3} & & \\ & & a_{3\,3} - \lambda & & \\ & & & \ddots & a_{n-1\,n} \\ & & & & a_{n\,n} - \lambda| \\
        &\tikznode{detAI}=\, \underline{(a_{1\,1} - \lambda)(a_{2\,2}\tikznode{detAI1} - \lambda)\ldots(a_{n\,n} - \lambda)} \\
        \\ \\ \\
    \end{aligned}$ 
        
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[<-] (detAI.south) to[out=270,in=0] 
    ($(detAI)+(-.46cm,-.65)$) node[below] {\scriptsize{\begin{tabular}{l}Le déterminant d'une \\ $\triangle$ supérieure est le produit \\ de ses éléments diagonaux.\end{tabular}}};
    \draw[->] (detAI1.south) to[out=270,in=90]
    ($(detAI1)+(1.25cm,-1.45)$) node[below] {\scriptsize{$\underline{\lambda = a_{1\,1},\, a_{2\,2},\, \ldots,\, a_{n\,n}}$}};
    \node[] at (7.15,1) {ne s'annule qu'en};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit the following line

```
\draw[->] ($(detAI1.south)-(0pt,4pt)$) to[out=270,in=90]
```

[image]

Comment: Ohhhh wow, thank you so much  very appreciated

Comment: accept and upvote if helped