# Symbol for trigonometric arc

Tags: symbols, arc

I want to type the notation same as the below picture.

[image]

Comment: I take it \overarc won't do.  The Comprehensive Symbol List had nothing better.  You could create one with TikZ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an overkill proposal, based on Ti*k*Z, which is somewhat inspired by [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324932/121799).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand{\overarcarrow}[1]{\ifmmode%
\tikz [baseline = (N.base)] {
      \node [inner sep = 0pt] (N) {$#1$};
      \draw [line width = 0.4pt,-{Stealth[scale=0.6]}] 
         ([xshift=0.1ex,yshift=0.3ex]N.north west) to[out=15,in=165]
         ([yshift=0.3ex]N.north east);
   }
\else   
\tikz [baseline = (N.base)] {
      \node [inner sep = 0pt] (N) {#1};
      \draw [line width = 0.4pt,-{Stealth[scale=0.6]}] 
         ([xshift=0.1ex,yshift=0.3ex]N.north west) to[out=15,in=165]
         ([yshift=0.3ex]N.north east);
   }
\fi   
}

\begin{document}
$\overline{AB}$ $\overarcarrow{AB}$ \overarcarrow{AB}
\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM**: A special version for @John Kormylo.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand{\overarcarrow}[1]{\ifmmode\mathchoice{%
\tikz [baseline = (N.base)] {
      \node [inner sep = 0pt] (N) {$\displaystyle#1$};
      \draw [line width = 0.4pt,-{Stealth[scale=0.6]}] 
         ([xshift=0.1ex,yshift=0.3ex]N.north west) to[out=15,in=165]
         ([yshift=0.3ex]N.north east);
   }
}{%
\tikz [baseline = (N.base)] {
      \node [inner sep = 0pt] (N) {$\textstyle#1$};
      \draw [line width = 0.4pt,-{Stealth[scale=0.6]}] 
         ([xshift=0.1ex,yshift=0.3ex]N.north west) to[out=15,in=165]
         ([yshift=0.3ex]N.north east);
   }
}{%
\tikz [baseline = (N.base)] {
      \node [inner sep = 0pt] (N) {$\scriptstyle#1$};
      \draw [line width = 0.3pt,-{Stealth[scale=0.6]}] 
         ([xshift=0.1ex,yshift=0.3ex]N.north west) to[out=15,in=165]
         ([yshift=0.3ex]N.north east);
   }
}{%
\tikz [baseline = (N.base)] {
      \node [inner sep = 0pt] (N) {$\scriptscriptstyle#1$};
      \draw [line width = 0.213pt,-{Stealth[scale=0.6]}] 
         ([xshift=0.1ex,yshift=0.3ex]N.north west) to[out=15,in=165]
         ([yshift=0.3ex]N.north east);
   }
}   
\else   
\tikz [baseline = (N.base)] {
      \node [inner sep = 0pt] (N) {#1};
      \draw [line width = 0.4pt,-{Stealth[scale=0.6]}] 
         ([xshift=0.1ex,yshift=0.3ex]N.north west) to[out=15,in=165]
         ([yshift=0.3ex]N.north east);
   }
\fi   
}

\begin{document}
$\overline{AB}$ $\overarcarrow{AB}$ \overarcarrow{AB}
$X_{\overarcarrow{AB}}$ $X_{Y_{\overarcarrow{AB}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Reformulate it for all 4 math styles using \mathchoice and it will be perfect ;-)

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks but I believe you're too optimistic, please see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122419/121799).  It is nontrivial to make the Ti*k*Z adopt the settings of the ambient world.

Comment: I am impressed!  Admit it, you feel better now.